# How to remove a role from someone who leaves a voice channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I am currently making a Discord bot that assigns a role when you enter a specific voice channel and removes it when you leave. Here is the code:

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {

const testChannel = newState.guild.channels.cache.find(c => c.name === ' 1h de travail');
const role = newState.guild.roles.cache.find(r => r.name === 'test');

if (newState.channelID === testChannel.id) {
  // Triggered when the user joined the channel we tested for
  if (!newState.member.roles.cache.has(role))
    newState.member.roles.add(role); 
    // Add the role to the user if they don't already have it
  }
  else {
    console.log('detected');

    if (oldState.voiceChannel !== undefined && newState.voiceChannel === undefined)
      oldState.member.roles.remove(role);
  }
});
```

My issue is that it doesn't actually remove the role. How can I make it do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`VoiceState`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState) doesn't have a `voiceChannel` property, so both your `oldState.voiceChannel` and `newState.voiceChannel` will be `undefined`. As you're checking if one of them is `undefined` AND the other one is not `undefined`, the if statement will always be `false` and you will never remove the role.

The good news is that `VoiceState` does have a `channel` property which you can use in this case. It is the channel that the member is connected to and has a type of [`VoiceChannel`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceState?scrollTo=channel).

The following code should work as expected. I also made it a bit simpler than the original.

```js
client.on('voiceStateUpdate', (oldState, newState) => {
  const testChannel = newState.guild.channels.cache.find(
    (c) => c.name === ' 1h de travail',
  );
  const role = newState.guild.roles.cache.find((r) => r.name === 'test');

  // Triggered when the user joined the channel we tested for
  if (newState.channelID === testChannel.id) {
    // Add the role to the user if they don't already have it
    if (!newState.member.roles.cache.has(role)) {
      newState.member.roles.add(role);
    }
  }

  // Triggered when the user left the voice channel
  if (oldState.channel && !newState.channel) {
    oldState.member.roles.remove(role);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works perfectly! Just changed the AND to an OR so that it would properly remove the role when switching channels and it's perfect now!